# row_to_json gives JSON with lower case field names

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-json

I have created a custom type as following:

```
create type my_type as (camelCasedIdentifier uuid, ...);
```

I am using this custom type `my_type` to define the field names in a JSON body:

```
select row_to_json(row(my_table.id, ...)::my_type) from my_table;
```

The reason why I thought using a custom type is useful is that this way, I don't have to define the JSON field names in every query (they differ from the table column names in my case), as you would have to do with `json_build_object()`.

The problem here however is that the field names are now all in lower case:

```
{"camelcasedidentifier":"d8f0a177-af13-4fa2-a2af-3bc8296d848e", ...}
```

I expected:

```
{"camelCasedIdentifier":"d8f0a177-af13-4fa2-a2af-3bc8296d848e", ...}
```

How can I fix this? I know this can be fixed by using `select json_build_object('camelCasedIdentifier', my_table.id) from my_table`, but I would rather not do that, as I will be forced to enumerate the JSON field names in every query.

Comment: `camelCasedIdentifier` is the same as `camelcasedidentifier` if you have a look at the definition of your type you will see that. See the manual for details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: I see. But in JSON world, field names are case sensitive (http://jsonrpc.org/historical/json-rpc-1-1-alt.html#service-procedure-and-parameter-names), so it would be ideal if I would preserve the case as defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQL [identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) are not case sensitive so your type was actually created with a field named `camelcasedidentifier`.

If you really need that, you have to use quoted identifiers:

```
create type my_type as ("camelCasedIdentifier" uuid, ...);
```

If you only use that type to do the JSON conversion this is acceptable, but using those dreaded quoted identifiers everywhere is going to give you more problems in the long run than they are worth it.

Comment: That's great, I did not know you could enforce the name by using quotes. Thanks! Regarding your remark: you are right, I am only introducing and using these types for JSON conversion, because without, it would be a pain to repeat the field names over and over again.